# Rails Typhoeus Curl Trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, curl, libcurl

I'm scratching my head on this error since similar errors refer to instances of compiling libcurl from source; however, I am just simply trying to get a former rails project running on my Ubuntu 12.04.

```
Exception Trace from Running Rails Application Server


/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.1.1/lib/ffi/library.rb:121:in `block in ffi_lib': Could not open library 'libcurl': libcurl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. (LoadError)
Could not open library 'libcurl.so': libcurl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.1.1/lib/ffi/library.rb:88:in `map'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.1.1/lib/ffi/library.rb:88:in `ffi_lib'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/typhoeus-0.4.2/lib/typhoeus/curl.rb:405:in `<module:Curl>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/typhoeus-0.4.2/lib/typhoeus/curl.rb:6:in `<module:Typhoeus>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/typhoeus-0.4.2/lib/typhoeus/curl.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/typhoeus-0.4.2/lib/typhoeus.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/panda-1.5.0/lib/panda/adapters/faraday.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/panda-1.5.0/lib/panda.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
```

Any help or commentary is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is libcurl properly installed? Typhoeus has no native extensions but it requires libcurl dynamic library (`.so`) since it works with the [FFI library](https://github.com/ffi/ffi):

```
# from lib/typhoeus/curl.rb
ffi_lib 'libcurl'
```

I would say that the development files (headers) are not needed so `sudo apt-get install libcurl3` should do the trick (otherwise install the devel version w/ SSL support via `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`).

Comment: I had problems with Graphiti , but installing libcurl4-openssl-dev did the trick as well....!! thanks a lot

Comment: the same issue, and the same solution :)

Answer (score 3):

sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding `libcurl-devel 7.57.0-1` to msys2 (on Windows) but it didn't help.  (`pacman -Ss libcurl` showed it as installed:

```
msys/libcurl 7.57.0-1 (libraries) [installed]
Multi-protocol file transfer library (runtime)
msys/libcurl-devel 7.57.0-1 (development) [installed]
Libcurl headers and libraries
```

So for anyone having the same problem on Windows, an easy way to get around the `LoadError: Could not open library 'libcurl'` is to:

- Take a `libcurl.dll` from one of the packages found here, https://curl.haxx.se/gknw.net/7.40.0/dist-w64/, and put it on the PATH.

  (I just put it under `\ruby24\bin\`)

Related questions about the same problem:

- [jekyll serve dependency error - Could not open 'lib curl'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47720302/jekyll-serve-dependency-error-could-not-open-lib-curl/47754520#47754520)
- [Typhoeus Windows installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22525093/typhoeus-windows-installation)
- [How to solve 'libcurl' not found with Rails on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39377541/how-to-solve-libcurl-not-found-with-rails-on-windows)
- [how to install libcurl on windows 7 64bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41114671/how-to-install-libcurl-on-windows-7-64bit)