# Typhoeus Windows installation

Tags: ruby, windows, typhoeus

Tried installing Typhoeus on a Windows 7 environment. Gem installs successfully but when trying to run a simple ruby script::
require 'typhoeus'

Typhoeus.get("www.google.com", verbose: true)

I get the following error::
D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.3-x86-mingw32/lib/ffi/library.rb:133:in `block in ffi_lib': Could not open l
 (LoadError)url': The specified module could not be found.
.
Could not open library 'libcurl.dll': The specified module could not be found.
.
Could not open library 'libcurl.so.4': The specified module could not be found.

I tried adding curl.exe and libcurl.dll that I found in one of the packages on the curl website but that didn't help. Not sure what to do at this point. Thnks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seem to have figured it out. If anyone is having the same issue, make sure to download the following package from [curl.haxx.se/download.html](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html)

Win32 2000/XP zip 7.34.0 libcurl SSL Günter Knauf 3.34 MB

Extract the bin directory to wherever and make sure to add it to your PATH. I also added .DLL to PATHEXT reset comp and it worked.

Comment: Thanks.You can also copy the contents of the bin dir from that download into Ruby21\bin

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem on Windows 7 x64 and [answered about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47754520/3066295).  [`Typhoeus`](https://github.com/benbalter/jekyll-remote-theme/blob/master/jekyll-remote-theme.gemspec#L20) requires `Ruby-FFI` [(see this answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705351/rails-typhoeus-curl-trouble) and `libcurl`.

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22542198/3066295) is a little out of date now, but the **same idea works**:

- Get a `libcurl.dll` from one of the packages here:
  https://curl.haxx.se/gknw.net/7.40.0/dist-w64/ and put it on the PATH.

(I did not add .DLL to the PATHEXT)