# How to solve 'libcurl' not found with Rails on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, curl, libcurl, rubymine

This is giving me a headache. I'm continuing a Rails project that started on Linux and I keep getting this when I run Puma on Ruby Mine:

```
Error:[rake --tasks] DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
rake aborted!
LoadError: Could not open library 'libcurl': The specified module could not be found.
Could not open library 'libcurl.dll': The specified module could not be found.
Could not open library 'libcurl.so.4': The specified module could not be found.
Could not open library 'libcurl.so.4.dll': The specified module could not be found.
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ffi-1.9.14-x86-mingw32/lib/ffi/library.rb:147:in `block in ffi_lib'
[...]
```

**Now, what have I tried?**

- I installed Puma successfully on Windows following [this steps](https://github.com/hicknhack-software/rails-disco/wiki/Installing-puma-on-windows)
- I downloaded `curl-7.50.1-win32-mingw` and put it on "C:/curl"
- I added C:/curl/bin and C:/curl/include to PATH
- I installed successfully curb gem with `gem install curb --platform=ruby -- --with-curl-lib=C:/curl/bin --with-curl-include=C:/curl/include`
- I put the .dll files in Ruby bin folder, installed the certificate in curl/bin and even run the curl.exe just in case.

I rebooted the machine but I keep seeing the same error.

I do not know what to do. **How to successfully install libcurl on Windows for use with Rails**

Comment: which version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Same problem. Win10, Ruby23

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Answer that worked for me (W10/Ruby2.6.0) was:

1. Download cURL from the following URL: https://curl.haxx.se/windows/ (I chose 64bit because that's the system I'm using)
2. Go into the archive and browse to `/bin`
3. Locate `libcurl_x64.dll` (it may be just `libcurl.dll`)
4. Extract to your local drive
5. Rename it to `libcurl.dll` if it has the `_x64` suffix
6. Cut + paste the file into the `/bin` directory of your Ruby installation

Answer (score 14):

I just had the same problem on Windows 7 x64 and [answered about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47754520/3066295).  (Similar to you, I tried a lot of things that I thought should work but didn't.)

**What *worked*** was:

- To take a `libcurl.dll` from one of the packages found here, https://curl.haxx.se/download.html#Win64, and put it on the **`PATH`**.

  (*Link was updated, but originally pointed to version `7.40`*)
- I just put it under `\ruby24\bin\`
- Maybe for you it's **`C:\Ruby24-x64\bin`**

(Here are things I tried that didn't work:)

- Putting on the `PATH`: the `cygcurl-4.dll` obtained from the current [Curl Download Wizard](https://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/?type=lib)
- Renaming the above `cygcurl-4.dll` to `libcurl.dll`and putting it on the `PATH`
- Installing the `msys2` package `libcurl-devel 7.57.0-1`
- Renaming the `msys-curl-4.dll` (from `msys2` found at `msys64\usr\bin`) to `libcurl.dll`

> I didn't try building curl / libcurl from the latest source because I already have the latest according to `pacman -Ss libcurl`:
>
> ```
> msys/libcurl 7.57.0-1 (libraries) [installed]
> Multi-protocol file transfer library (runtime)
>
> msys/libcurl-devel 7.57.0-1 (development) [installed]
> Libcurl headers and libraries
> ```

More details about this in these other questions:

- [jekyll serve dependency error - Could not open 'lib curl'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47720302/jekyll-serve-dependency-error-could-not-open-lib-curl/47754520#47754520)
- [Typhoeus Windows installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22525093/typhoeus-windows-installation)
- [Rails Typhoeus Curl Trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705351/rails-typhoeus-curl-trouble)
- [how to install libcurl on windows 7 64bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41114671/how-to-install-libcurl-on-windows-7-64bit)

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and tried the same steps that OP has listed. After breaking my head, cursing the existence of windows for some time and almost convincing the client to shift to a nix server I figured the libcurl.dll that I downloaded from https://curl.haxx.se/ (as suggested in all related posts) was corrupt.

Downloaded the one provided here http://www.dlldownloader.com/libcurl-dll/ and viola the ffi was able to load this one.

Hope this helps anyone else facing this issue

Comment: This is what worked for me. Just copy the downloaded dll file to RubyX folder

Answer (score 2):

For anyone running Ruby 2.5 on Windows, my solution was similar to the top solutions however I had to move it to place the file in both the \bin folder and \bin\ruby_builtin_dlls folder to work.

Some other things is that I downloaded the 64bit version and changed its name to libcurl.dll. Also make sure to restart your IDE/terminal and then try to start the server again.

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions worked for me - no matter what I tried, libcurl failed to load.

I then did the following:

1. Created a mini Ruby program that just tried loading the dll:

```
require 'ffi'

FFI::DynamicLibrary.open("libcurl", FFI::DynamicLibrary::RTLD_LAZY | FFI::DynamicLibrary::RTLD_LOCAL)
```

2. Ran [procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and filtered by ruby.exe process and any path containing "dll"

As a result, I saw the following:

**C:\Ruby27-x64\bin\libzstd.dll - NAME NOT FOUND**

That gave me an idea that I was missing a dependency. The libzstd.dll file is part of the mingw-w64-x86_64-zstd package but luckily I just had it sitting on my drive elsewhere (as part of the GIMP installation).

I copied libzstd.dll to C:\Ruby27-x64\bin and the problem was solved. Of course, I had libcurl.dll in my path already (got it from https://curl.haxx.se/windows)

Answer (score 0):

I want to use wpscan, but i get libcurl error
OK, if you also get the same error, then in a very easy way I will try to give the solution.

Just copy the libcurl.dll file to system32 if your windows is 32 bit,

If your windows 64 bit copied to syswo64.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the issue is caused by a missing lib as said in the error, So the solution is to download the lib here: http://www.dlldownloader.com/libcurl-dll/ and navigate to the ruby folder under bin and drop it there make sure to rename the downloaded .dll file to this exact one: libcurl.dll else won't work even after.

Answer (score 0):

The solution which worked for me was download the dll, keep the exact name libcurl.dll and copy it to c:\windows\system32

Answer (score -1):

If you're using WSL on Windows 10 (Make sure to update to Ubuntu 16.04) the following instructions worked perfectly for me.  You might need to completely wipe what you have installed however. 
Within bash:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties libffi-dev postgresql-client-common postgresql-client libpq-dev
```

And then to build our path and plugin directory for rbenv:

```
cd
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL
```

Finally we come to ruby:

```
rbenv install 2.4.1
rbenv global 2.4.1
```

Then bundler:

```
gem install bundler
rbenv rehash
```

Now our prerequisites:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

And then finally Rails:

```
gem install rails
rbenv rehash
```