# SSL certificate is not OK with Cocoapods CDN

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

When I run pod install in the ios directory of my my react native project, i get the error:
`CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-version.yml Response: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK`

It takes about a minute after the previous local podspec is fetched before it arrives at this error, so it seems like a timeout to me.

I installed ruby and curl very recently. The way I installed curl was with a dll file off of https://curl.haxx.se/windows/ ; I followed the directions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54520917/15664214)

I'm trying to add expo-modules to project with `npx install-expo-modules@latest`

Comment: when I `curl https://cdn.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-version.yml`, I get
```
---
min: 1.0.0
last: 1.12.1
prefix_lengths:
- 1
- 1
- 1
```
so not an ssl issue?

Comment: I'm using cocoapods for windows - when I sent it to my mac it worked and then I sent it back so I am chilling.