# how to install libcurl on windows 7 64bit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, libcurl

I am getting the following error while installing:

`C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/json_web_token-0.3.2/lib/json_web_token.rb:36: warning: already initialized constant JWT`

`C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jwt-1.5.6/lib/jwt/json.rb:4: warning: previous definition of JWT was here
rake aborted!`

`LoadError: Could not open library 'libcurl': The specified module could not be found.`

`.
Could not open library 'libcurl.dll': The specified module could not be found.`

`.
Could not open library 'libcurl.so.4': The specified module could not be found.`

`.
Could not open library 'libcurl.so.4.dll': The specified module could not be found.`

`D:/data/catarse/config/application.rb:8:in`'

`D:/data/catarse/Rakefile:4:in`'

`(See full trace by running task with --trace)`

Answer (score 1):

An easy way I got around the `LoadError: Could not open library 'libcurl'` was to:

- Take a `libcurl.dll` from one of the packages found here, https://curl.haxx.se/download.html#Win64, and put it on the PATH.

  (I just put it under `\ruby24\bin\`)

  (*Link was updated, but originally pointed to version `7.40`*)

For further details, see the answers to these questions:

- [jekyll serve dependency error - Could not open 'lib curl'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47720302/jekyll-serve-dependency-error-could-not-open-lib-curl/47754520#47754520)
- [Typhoeus Windows installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22525093/typhoeus-windows-installation)
- [How to solve 'libcurl' not found with Rails on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39377541/how-to-solve-libcurl-not-found-with-rails-on-windows)
- [Rails Typhoeus Curl Trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705351/rails-typhoeus-curl-trouble)

Comment: this link is broken: https://curl.haxx.se/gknw.net/7.40.0/dist-w64/
use this instead: https://curl.haxx.se/download.html