# jekyll serve dependency error - Could not open 'lib curl'

Tags: ruby, jekyll, github-pages

I am trying to run `bundle exec jekyll serve` but it comes up with the error:

`Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have jekyll-remote-theme or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. The full error message from Ruby is: 'Could not open library 'libcurl': The specified module could not be found. . Could not open library 'libcurl.dll': The specified module could not be found. . Could not open library 'libcurl.so.4': The specified module could not be found. . Could not open library 'libcurl.so.4.dll': The specified module could not be found. ' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at https://jekyllrb.com/help/!
jekyll 3.6.2 | Error:  jekyll-remote-theme`

So I checked if curl was installed:

`$ curl --version
curl 7.50.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) libcurl/7.50.1 OpenSSL/1.0.2h zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.33 libssh2/1.7.0 nghttp2/1.13.0 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: IDN IPv6 Largefile SSPI Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 Metalink`

I've searched for similar questions but the solutions don't seem to be relevant to my issue. I'm new to Jekyll and Ruby and I just wanted to be able to view my Github Pages offline.

I am using Windows 7 64-bit. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: v171 of the github pages gem added jekyll-remote-theme as a dependency. Please see the official issue here: https://github.com/github/pages-gem/issues/509

Comment: The error is issue #17 at the jekyll-remote-theme repository: https://github.com/benbalter/jekyll-remote-theme/issues/17

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve 'libcurl' not found with Rails on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39377541/how-to-solve-libcurl-not-found-with-rails-on-windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My work around was to omit the Jekyll plugins from the Gemfile.

Original Gemfile:

`source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'github-pages', group: :jekyll_plugins`

New:

`source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'github-pages'`

However, if you need to use the plugins, check out [TT--](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3066295/tt)'s answer below. I couldn't get it working myself, but it is the exact same problem so if it worked for him I guess it should work.

Comment: This is exactly what I told you in my answer, just include gihub-pages gem.

Comment: Yeah I suppose, I just wanted to clarify and make the answer as simple as possible, so people who are new to Jekyll like me can understand. If you want to edit your answer to be as clear as mine I can delete my answer and re-mark you as the solution if you want.

Comment: ty, after removing the group the error is gone.
Can you explain me what's the difference now?

Answer (score 4):

#### Here's what **worked for me:**

- Obtain a `libcurl.dll` from one of the packages here:

  **https://curl.se/download.html#Win64**

  (*formerly* https://curl.haxx.se/download.html#Win64)

(*Link was updated, but originally pointed to version `7.40`*)

- Put it on the **`PATH`** somehow.

  - (I just put it under **`\ruby24\bin\`**)
  - Maybe for you it's **`C:\Ruby24-x64\bin`**, which others have suggested.

##### About the problem

- Seems to be coming from Ruby-FFI. ([as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705351/rails-typhoeus-curl-trouble))
- I got the same error above about the dependencies of `jekyll-remote-theme`.

  ([One of them is `typhoeus`](https://github.com/benbalter/jekyll-remote-theme/blob/master/jekyll-remote-theme.gemspec#L20) which uses FFI.)
- Also, doing a `github-pages health-check` showed this error :

```sh
    ffi-1.9.18-x64-mingw32/lib/ffi/library.rb:147:in `block in ffi_lib': Could not 
    open libra (LoadError): The specified module could not be found.
    Could not open library 'libcurl.dll': The specified module could not be found.
    Could not open library 'libcurl.so.4': The specified module could not be 
    found.
    Could not open library 'libcurl.so.4.dll': The specified module could not be 
    found.
```

##### Things I tried that *didn't work*:

- Putting on the PATH the `cygcurl-4.dll` obtained from the current [Curl Download Wizard](https://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/?type=lib)
- Renaming the above `cygcurl-4.dll` to `libcurl.dll`and putting it on the PATH
- Installing the `msys2` package `libcurl-devel 7.57.0-1`
- Renaming the `msys-curl-4.dll` (from `msys2` found at `msys64\usr\bin`) to `libcurl.dll`

**Didn't try:**

- Building curl / libcurl from the latest source. Because I already had the latest according to `pacman -Ss libcurl`:

  `msys/libcurl 7.57.0-1 (libraries) [installed] Multi-protocol file transfer library (runtime)`

  `msys/libcurl-devel 7.57.0-1 (development) [installed] Libcurl headers and libraries`

Comment: I used the package [curl-7.40.0-devel-mingw64.zip](https://curl.haxx.se/gknw.net/7.40.0/dist-w64/curl-7.40.0-devel-mingw64.zip), therein the path `curl-7.40.0-devel-mingw64\bin`. It worked. Thank you!

Comment: In 2021, this is still the most detailed and effective answer. Be careful though, the link to curl/haxx.se is confusing. The only link that gave me a downloadable file (without installing over CLI) was the link pointing to `the curl project`s download site

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. My solution was the one of TT--, but I put the downloaded file `libcurl.dll` here:

```
C:\Ruby24-x64\bin
```

Any other folder got me the same error, even if it was in the PATH.

Answer (score -1):

The problem I see is mixing the usage of bundle and gem commands, considering you have a Gemfile with just the github-pages gem in your Jekyll root path, do this:

```
bundle install
bundle exec jekyll serve
```

That should create a folder with all needed dependencies and then execute the newly installed Jekyll version.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I had the Gemfile containing: 

`source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'github-pages', group: :jekyll_plugins`

and removed the ", group: :jekyll_plugins" part and it worked.

Comment: @Leeton, well that is one way to do it, since you have removed the dependency on jekyll-remote-theme and therefore on libcurl, but according to https://pages.github.com/versions, those are `github-pages` dependencies

Comment: @TT-- Oh I see. Well it seems to be fine without it. I tried your solution but it doesn't seem to change anything. I might have done it wrong but I added C:/users/<username>/libcurl to PATH (for some reason) with libcurl.dll found at that directory.

Comment: assuming <username> has no spaces, you may have to restart your terminal session (or computer) so that the updated PATH is used